# Does Neo4j allow function based indexes

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I want to create several indexes containing the results of user-defined functions on one or more node properties in neo4j.

example properties: name, postcode

function: name_1st_3_chars + postcode

name: "dave", postcode: "nw14da"

function value: davnw14da

I want to be able to do a very fast node lookup based on the function values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with some java coding. With your `GraphDatabaseService` register a [`TransactionEventHandler`](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.6/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/event/TransactionEventHandler.html). TransactionEventHandlers provide callback functions hooking into the transaction mechanism. This way can do the described calculation of a "function property". The calculated property needs to be stored using `setProperty`.

To establish the index, use `CREATE INDEX ON :MyLabel(myfunctionProperty)`.

With that in place a query like `MATCH (something:MyLabel) WHERE something.myfuntionPropery = 'davnw14da' RETURN something` will use the declared index.